# Каким sql запросом удалить содержимое таблицы?

Tags: sql, wordpress, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Есть БД Mysql для Wordpress.
В ней есть таблица `wp_signups`.
Каким sql запросом удалить всех юзеров из таблицы `wp_signups`, кроме первых десяти?

Comment: А что такое "первые 10" ? вообще что то типа delete from table where XXX>N, где N возможно 10, а может и нет, в зависимости от содержимого таблицы

Comment: В SQL нет понятия "первые N записей", первые записи зависят от сортировки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Для начала нужно определить, как вы определяете первые 10 записей?
Поскольку никакого порядка по умолчанию нет ни в таблице реляционной модели, ни в SQL стандартах, основывающихся на реляционной модели, ни в MySql, то необходимо в явном виде указать порядок.

См. [Таблица](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database))

> However, the database system does not guarantee any ordering of the
>   rows unless an ORDER BY clause is specified in the SELECT statement
>   that queries the table

По скольку автор вопроса не указал структуру таблицы, будем считать что это таблица по следующей схеме: [Database Description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), содержит ключ user_login и поле registered (datetime), по которому мы берем первые 10 записей в порядке возрастания даты. Я не знаю точно, является-ли user_login ключем таблицы. Нужно исследовать этот вопрос отдельно, и установить - что на самом деле является ключем, прежде чем на самом деле манипулировать таблицей.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_signups` WHERE `user_login` NOT IN (
    SELECT `user_login` FROM `wp_signups`
    ORDER BY `registered`
    LIMIT 0, 10
);
```

Диалект позволяет сделать запрос с клаузой LIMIT без клаузы ORDER BY, это нормально для запросов, которым не важен состав ответа, например - если мы последовательно обрабатываем записи пачками, и стираем после обработки, но следует иметь ввиду, насколько опасным может быть подобный запрос без ORDER BY, если порядок на самом деле важен. Порядок может отличаться от версии к версии MySql, от порядка вставки в таблицу, от текущего плана оптимизации, так что тот факт, что однажды этот запрос сработал "правильно" не означает, что он будет так работать всегда.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `wp_signups` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `wp_signups`  ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 10);
```

Comment: типичный выстрел в ногу. Одному б*гу известно что выдаст `SELECT `id` FROM `wp_signups` LIMIT 0, 10` поскольку не задан признак сортировки

Comment: @AntonioK а там точно такие кавычки, а не 'wp_signups'?

Comment: @NickVolynkin инфа 100%, так экранируются названия таблиц и полей

Comment: @Barmaley, я сейчас не могу вспомнить, ни одного случая, когда бы `select * from table` (без явного указания сортировки!) выводил записи не в хронологической последовательности... Можешь привести пример?

Comment: Давайте сначала уточним что такое хронологическая последовательность :)

Comment: @SergeySereda Реляционная модель не определяет какого-либо порядка по умолчанию. Если MySql определяет это как-то по другому - пришлите ссылку.

Comment: @Barmaley :) в доннам случае, я подразумевал последовательность в которой добавляются записи в таблицу. Например, если таблица имеет три записи (предположим, что первая была добавлена позавчера, вторая вчера, а третья сегодня), то `SELECT` без явного указания сортировки, выводит все записи в последовательности в которой они добавлялись в таблицу (позавчерашняя, вчерашняя, сегодняшняя).

Comment: Легко написать например что-то типа `ALTER TABLE wp_signups ORDER BY id DESC` и после этого ваш `select` будет выдавать все с точностью до наоборот...

Comment: @Barmaley, спасибо...

Comment: Поправьте свой селект с включением сортировки